# Show that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2= (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ has infinitely many solutions in integers $x, y, z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

> Show that the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2= (x-y)(y-z)(z-x)$ has infinitely many solutions in integers $x, y, z$.

It seems like if I find a set of $x,y,z$ that satisfy this for any values that will prove it. But how do I find that set?

Comment: If we try $y=1$ and $z=0$, then we get $x^2+1 = (x-1)(-x)$. So $x^2+1 = -x^2+x.$ Okay, that didn't quite work; we want to the LHS and the RHS to be equal. So try different choices for $y=$ some value, or polynomial of $x$, and $z=$ some value, or polynomial of $x$, until the LHS equals the RHS. When this happens, you will know that the equation holds for all $x$, given the system of assumptions you've found.

Comment: How do you know, Puzzled, that the equation does have infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Are complex solution allowed?

Comment: One family of solution $$(x,y,z) = ((2u-1)(1+6u^2), 2u(1+6u^2), (2u+1)(1+6u^2))$$ Somehow I feel I have seen this sort of parametrization before.